# How do I verify if redis dump was successfully restored?

Tags: bash, docker, redis, restore

I have a bash script that

- downloads a redis dump from S3
- stops any running docker containers with the name "my_redis_container"
- starts a new docker container "my_redis_container" and copies the downloaded dump file into the data directory of this container
- waits for this docker container to be ready

When I manually jump into the container and run redis-cli, I can see all the keys
But how do I verify if the restore was successful or not inside the bash script. Would it be safe to say that dbsize > 0 means restore was successful? Is there a more appropriate way?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
 
# https://www.shellcheck.net/ VERIFIED
set -e
set -E
set -o pipefail
set -u
# set -x

log="/tmp/error.txt"
exec 2>>"$log"

handle_error() {    
    # ...handle error
    exit 1
}

handle_exit() {
    # ...handle exit
    exit 0
}

trap 'handle_exit $?' EXIT
trap 'handle_error $?' ERR

bucket='something-something'
container_name="my_redis_container"
dump_file_directory="/tmp"
host="localhost"
port="6379"

dump_file_name=$(aws s3 ls $bucket --recursive | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}')

aws s3 cp "s3://${bucket}/${dump_file_name}"  "/tmp/${dump_file_name}"

docker ps -aq --filter "name=${container_name}" | grep -q . && docker stop "${container_name}" && docker rm -fv "${container_name}"

docker run --detach --name "${container_name}" --publish "${port}:${port}" --volume "/tmp/${dump_file_name}:/data/dump.rdb" redis

# Wait for the Docker container to be ready
until docker exec -it "${container_name}" redis-cli -h "${host}" -p "${port}" ping; do
    sleep 1
done

# HOW TO VERIFY IF REDIS WAS RESTORED SUCCESSFULLY HERE???
```

Comment: It seems like you're already using the `docker exec` debugging tool to get access to `redis-cli` and you can use this to make arbitrary Redis calls.  (I'd recommend installing the tool on the host system the same way you have the AWS CLI.)

Comment: @DavidMaze what sort of standard command lets you verify if the dump was successful or not or do I have to manually find something from my application to do so

Comment: Maybe you could [`GET`](https://redis.io/commands/get/) some known key?  You'd do this the exact same way you'd do this without Docker.